# Самопроизвольное изменение интервала смены слайдов в слайдере на js с применением JQuery

Tags: javascript

Ошибка, которую сложно отловить. Если оставить вкладку с данным слайдером открытой, заниматься своими делами в браузере, а затем вернуться, можно обнаружить, что слайды сменяются без задержки, один за другим. Спустя какое-то время они вновь начинают сменятся согласно интервалу. Такое ощущение, словно браузер отсчитал, сколько должно было произойти смены слайдов и без остановки отсчитывает это количество. Я не знаю, что провоцирует данную ошибку, и сколько нужно ждать, всегда по-разному.

Я уже задавал вопрос с данным кодом, но там не было кнопок слайда и связанных функций. Надо сказать, что такой ошибки не наблюдалось. Потому скидываю весь код.

Во время данной ошибки, виден один эффект, который может помочь.
В норме сменяется слайд, сменяется активная кнопка. Во время данной ошибки, кнопка остается активной в течение 2-х циклов слайдера, в смысле в слайдере на 3 слайда (как здесь) сменяется 6 слайдов, и только потом следующая кнопка становится активной.

Кто знает, что это может быть, как тестировать данные ошибки, как исправить? Очень надо! Буду очень благодарен.

```js
var slider = {
  // Находит по class порядковый номер (Возьмет первую цифру в классе)
  number: function(elem) {
    return elem.attr('class').match(/\d+/g)[0] - 1;
  },

  // Принимает данные:
  // slider - слайдер,
  // slide - элементы, которые будут "перемещаться",
  // band - лента содержащая элементы, она на самом деле перемещается
  // interval - интервал, через который будет меняться слайд, по умолчанию 3 секунды
  init: function(slider, slide, band, interval) {

    // Если не объявлен, выставляем по умолчанию
    interval = (interval) ? interval : 3000;

    // Находим нужные элементы
    var buttons = $(slider).children();
    var slides = $(slide);
    var film = $(band);

    // Если не существует таких объектов, завершаем функцию
    if (!buttons[0] && !slides[0] && !film[0]) {
      return;
    }

    // Если количество кнопок и картинок не равно, завершаем функцию
    if (buttons.length !== slides.length) {
      return;
    }

    // Для перемещений, номер активной кнопки и элемента
    var number = 1;

    // Ловим контекст
    var cnxFunc = this;

    // При нажатии
    buttons.click(function() {

      // Находим номер кнопки и записываем, чтобы перемещалось с него
      number = cnxFunc.number($(this));

      // Приводим в движение ленту
      cnxFunc.mover(number, buttons, film, slides);
    });

    // Повторяем через определенное время
    setInterval(function() {

      // Приводим в движение ленту
      cnxFunc.mover(number, buttons, film, slides);

      // Шагаем на следующую. Если дошли до конца, то начинаем сначала
      (number === slides.length - 1) ? number = 0: number++;
    }, interval);
  },

  // number - номер активного слайда
  // buttons - массив кнопок
  // band - лента со слайдами
  // slides - массив слайдов
  mover: function(number, buttons, band, slides) {

    // Класс активной кнопки, должен содержать "_active"
    var activeClass = this.getActiveClass(buttons);

    // Отступ
    var shift = this.getShift(slides);

    // Отрисовка стилей кнопок
    this.renderStyleButtons(buttons, buttons.eq(number), activeClass);

    // Анимированное перемещение
    band.animate({
      left: -shift[number]
    }, 500);
  },

  // Отрисовка стилей кнопок
  renderStyleButtons: function(buttons, button, activeClass) {
    buttons.removeClass(activeClass);
    button.addClass(activeClass);
  },

  // Принимает массив слайдов, возвращает массив с отступами
  getShift: function(slides) {

    // Отступ
    var shift = [];
    shift[0] = 0;

    // Присваиваем значения отступов для каждого слайда
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length - 1; i++) {
      shift[i + 1] = shift[i] + slides.eq(i).width();
    }

    return shift;
  },

  // Принимает массив кнопок, возвращает класс делающий кнопку активной.
  // Активный класс должен содержать "_active"
  getActiveClass: function(buttons) {

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      // Если классы данной кнопки содердет "_active", то
      // Разбиваем класс по пробелу, и находим класс, содержащий "_active"
      // Возвращаем этот класс
      if (buttons.eq(i).attr('class').match(/_active(_)?/)) {

        // Записываем все классы данной кнопки в виде массива
        var classes = buttons.eq(i).attr('class').split(' ');

        // Бежим по массиву классов, возвращаем класс, содержащий "_active"
        for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
          if (classes[j].match(/_active(_)?/)) {
            return classes[j];
          }
        }

      }
    }
  },
};
slider.init('.slider', '.slide', '.band')
```

```css
.window {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 185px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.band {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide_1 {
  background: #fcf;
}

.slide_2 {
  background: #cff;
}

.slide_3 {
  background: #ffc;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider_button {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #88f;
  outline: none;
}

.slider_button:hover {
  background: #f88;
}

.slider_button_active {
  background: #f88;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='window'>
  <div class='slider'>
    <button class='slider_id_1 slider_button slider_button_active'></button>
    <button class='slider_id_2 slider_button'></button>
    <button class='slider_id_3 slider_button'></button>
  </div>
  <div class='band'>
    <div class='slide slide_1'></div>
    <div class='slide slide_2'></div>
    <div class='slide slide_3'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну вот зачем эта никому не нужная приписка в заголовке "Вопрос для знатоков" ? Кто знает - тот поможет. А заголовок должен отражать суть (или хоть как-то четко описывать), а не обращение к знатокам, мольбы аллаху и строки из анекдота

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это дает автору вопроса возможность ощущать себя этаким Ворошиловым

Comment: @Igor, обратите внимание на то, что он ваш тёзка! Мне вот очень хочется знать получите ли вы сообщение о том, что вам ответили?

Comment: @Bharata Да, это интересно.