# onUnload событие и противоположность ему

Tags: javascript

Есть слайдер, перелистывающий картинки.

Я столкнулся с очень интересным поведением:

Когда я возвращаюсь на страницу через какое-то время, периодически, он начинает работать без остановок. Т.е. есть некий интервал, допустим 5 сек, и в нормальном состоянии он перелистывает картинки с этим интервалом. Но, если на какое-то время перейти на другие вкладки, а затем вернуться, слайдер будет работать непрерывно, без интервалов.

Отловить сложно, не всегда появляется этот эффект

[Здесь мой предыдущий вопрос, где можно посмотреть код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759635/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Я знаю точно, что когда покидаешь вкладку, браузер самопроизвольно приостанавливает процессы на странице, в том числе и программу слайдера.

Я предполагаю, что браузер каким-то образом запоминает, сколько он должен был слайдов перелистнуть и при возврате на страницу, он быстро быстро выполняет все операции.

Родилась идея: использовать событие `onUnload`, чтобы приостанавливать слайдер, и когда пользователь возвращается на вкладку, хочу запускать слайдер.

Но я не знаю такого события. Есть ли событие возврата на вкладку или как можно решить описанную проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны события `onblur` и `onfocus` объекта `window`.

Сохраняйте значение, возвращаемое функцией `setInterval` и вызывайте `clearInterval` с этим параметром.

Comment: Понаделал себе Игорь учётных записей и отвечает сам себе... А я тут думаю, как он умудряется быть на первом месте и столько очков иметь! А разгадочка то вот! :-) **ШУЧУ**

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно это то, что нужно! Работает! :)